# Boostrap - Pull col-md-3 above col-md-6 at first breakpoint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two columns:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    ...main content here
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    ...sidebar content here
</div>
```

I want the `col-md-3` on the right side until the first breakpoint then on top thereafter at smaller viewports. I played around with pushing and pulling columns, but couldn't figure out how to display correctly. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/aNB3xEdoUa)

The idea is that the top div will always break above.  Since we want the top div in the right position we push it to the right by the offset of the other column which is 9.  Then we pull the bottom div back 3 columns to put it in the left position.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
    ...sidebar content here
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3">
    ...main content here
</div>
```